# How do i get all getters methods of java class and invoke them . Should also transform data

Tags: java

My java class structure :

```
  public class Qei implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 2902444063726917000L;
     private Integer qeiMasterId;
     private String qeiId;
     @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = NMTCConstants.DATEFORMAT)
     private Date originalDate;
     private BigDecimal amount;
     @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = NMTCConstants.DATEFORMAT)
      private Date complianceEndDate;
      private BigDecimal perAllocAgreementPercent;
      private BigDecimal minRequiredPercent;
      private Integer allocationYear;
      private DealDetail dealDetail;
      private List<Qlici> qliciInfo;
    }
```

my class having inner classes and List calss. how d i call getters of all so that i can invoke them through Method refernce.
At present , iam just calling all getters methods with names which is overlaoding the class.*

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please add more details please

Comment: I think this may help you https://asgteach.com/2012/11/finding-getters-and-setters-with-java-reflection/

Comment: @KunalVohra above mentioned is my pojo class. I need all getter methods from that class to access the values of getters. So my Class having two classes again( DealDetail,List<> class) . I want those class getters also

Comment: @SaggioVecchino  If a class has other set of classes like I have i.e, (DealDetail,List<class>) as above mentioned

Comment: which java version are you using/targeting?

Comment: java8 version@matt

Comment: Java 14 has Record classes which might do what you're after. Also there is [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) which lets you create properties automatically.

Comment: @Raj, Il Saggio Vecchino is right.  You can iterate the attributes as well, not only methods name start with get/set, If the attribute is matching your interested type/package.class, then go for it's get/set methods again.